# Fisheye lens calibration with opencv 3.0 beta

Tags: c++, opencv, fisheye, opencv3.0

I would like calibrate a fisheye lens with this code:

```
bool found = findChessboardCorners( view, s.boardSize, pointBuf, CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK | CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);
vector<vector<Point2f> > imagePoints;
imagePoints.push_back(pointBuf);
Mat cameraMatrix, distCoeffs;
vector<Mat> rvecs, tvecs;
vector<float> reprojErrs;
vector<vector<Point3f> > objectPoints(1);
s.flag = fisheye::CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC|fisheye::CALIB_FIX_SKEW|fisheye::CALIB_FIX_K1;
calcBoardCornerPositions(s.boardSize, s.squareSize, objectPoints[0], s.calibrationPattern);
double rms = fisheye::calibrate(objectPoints, imagePoints, view.size(), cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs, s.flag);
```

I have no problem to find the chessboard but I have an assert error during the calibration:

> Assertion failed ((flags & FIXED_TYPE) != 0) in cv::_InputArray::type, file ......\sources\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 1792

So I tried to initialized `rvecs` like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < imagePoints.size() ; ++i)
{
    rvecs.push_back(Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_64FC3));
}
```

but with this I get another assert :

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= i && i < (int)v.size()) in cv::_InputArray::getMat, file ......\sources\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 1170

How `rvecs` and `tvecs` must be declared and initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the following:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2d> > imagePoints(n_images);
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3d> > objectPoints(n_images);

//...

cv::Matx33d K;
cv::Vec4d D;
std::vector<cv::Vec3d> rvec;
std::vector<cv::Vec3d> tvec;

cv::fisheye::calibrate(
     objectPoints, imagePoints, imageSize, 
     K, D, rvec, tvec, flag, 
     cv::TermCriteria(3, 20, 1e-6)
);
```

See the example here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/6df1198e8b1ea4925cbce943a1dc6549f27d8be2/modules/calib3d/test/test_fisheye.cpp